# Конвертация RAW в RGB

Tags: c++, графика, bitmap, обработка-изображений

Есть изображение формата RAW, которое представляет собой матрицу x*y 2-х байтовых значений оттенков серого. 
Вопрос: как это дело привести к RGB, чтобы сохранить изображение в формате jpeg/bmp?

Answer (score 2):

Если не вдаваться в детали реализации, то в общем случае, чтобы оттенок серого `v` перевести в RGB, нужно, чтобы R, G и B были равны `v`. Что-то вроде:

```
RGB getRgbFromGray(int gray) {
    return RGB(gray, gray, gray);
}
```

Само собой, я исхожу из предположения, что вы пользуетесь готовой библиотекой, которая сама сформирует изображение нужного формата из матрицы RGB, поскольку просто перевода оттенков серого из RAW в RGB представление недостаточно для того, чтобы получить готовый BMP или JPEG, так как эти форматы сжатия/хранения информации изображения довольно сложны и хранят данные в своем собственном представлении.